# InputSelect y InputText no mantiene la selección en una lista de formularios

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Pretendo hacer en una página una lista de formularios con 3 InputSelect, un InputText y botón de guardar.

Los formularios se generan bien, pero no cada vez que selecciono alguna opción o introduzco un texto, al salir del control se restaura al estado inicial.

Este es mi código:

```
@page "/Internado/SeguimientoInternado"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using GestionCasaMadre.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@if (alumnos != null)
    {
    <h4>Alumnos:</h4>
    @foreach (AlumnoViewModel alumno in alumnos)
        {
        SeguimientosInterno seguimiento;
        seguimiento = new SeguimientosInterno();
        seguimiento.IdAlumno = alumno.Id;
        
        <EditForm Model="@seguimiento">
                <div class="divEnlinea">
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 200px;">@alumno.NombreAlumno</div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 75px;">@alumno.IdCurso</div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 100px;">
                    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="seguimiento.PuntualidadEstudios">
                                <option value="">ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                                <option value="SIEMPRE">SIEMPRE</option>
                                <option value="CASI SIEMPRE">CASI SIEMPRE</option>
                                <option value="A VECES">A VECES</option>
                                <option value="CASI NUNCA">CASI NUNCA</option>
                                <option value="NUNCA">NUNCA</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 100px;">
                    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="@seguimiento.PuntualidadLevantarse">
                        <option value="">ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="SIEMPRE">SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="CASI SIEMPRE">CASI SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="A VECES">A VECES</option>
                        <option value="CASI NUNCA">CASI NUNCA</option>
                        <option value="NUNCA">NUNCA</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea ">
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@seguimiento.Observaciones" />
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea "><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="(()=>Guardar(seguimiento))"><span class="oi oi-reload"> Guardar</span></button></div>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
        }
    }
@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
        await this.CargaAlumnos();
        }

    protected async Task CargaAlumnos()
        {
        //ELIMINADO POR LIMPIEZA
        }
    protected void Guardar(SeguimientosInterno seguimiento)
        {
        string idalumno = seguimiento.IdAlumno;
        string p = seguimiento.PuntualidadEstudios;
        }
}
```

Si me creo una página solo con un formulario (sin el foreach) en cambio si funciona bien:

```
@page "/Seguimiento"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using GestionCasaMadre.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS


<div class="row">
    <div class="offset-1 col-md-10">
        <p>@estado</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <h4>Alumnos:</h4>
        
        
        <EditForm Model="@seguimiento">
                <div class="divEnlinea">
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 200px;">AAAA</div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 55px;">BB</div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 100px;">
                    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="seguimiento.PuntualidadEstudios">
                                <option value="">ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                                <option value="SIEMPRE">SIEMPRE</option>
                                <option value="CASI SIEMPRE">CASI SIEMPRE</option>
                                <option value="A VECES">A VECES</option>
                                <option value="CASI NUNCA">CASI NUNCA</option>
                                <option value="NUNCA">NUNCA</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 100px;">
                    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="@seguimiento.PuntualidadLevantarse">
                        <option value="">ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="SIEMPRE">SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="CASI SIEMPRE">CASI SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="A VECES">A VECES</option>
                        <option value="CASI NUNCA">CASI NUNCA</option>
                        <option value="NUNCA">NUNCA</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea "><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="(()=>Guardar(seguimiento))"><span class="oi oi-reload"> Guardar</span></button></div>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    

@code {
    private string estado;
    private SeguimientosInterno seguimiento = null;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
        seguimiento = new SeguimientosInterno();
        seguimiento.IdAlumno = "001";
        }

    
    protected void Guardar(SeguimientosInterno seguimiento)
        {
        string idalumno = seguimiento.IdAlumno;
        string p = seguimiento.PuntualidadEstudios;
        }
}
```

Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: A que te refieres con que se restaura al estado original?? Por otro lado en los select estas haciendo bind a un mismo objeto para todas las iteraciones del foreach

Comment: Da igual la opción que elija del select que siempre vuelve a "ELIGE UNA OPCION" o en caso del text se borra. Creo un nuevo objeto local en cada iteracion del foreach, no se si habrá otra forma pero el número de iteraciones no siempre es igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu clase `AlumnoViewModel` debe contener una objeto `SeguimientosInterno`

Te dejo un ejemplo para que lo revises.

```
@if (alumnos != null)
{
    <h4>Alumnos:</h4>
    @foreach (AlumnoViewModel alumno in alumnos)
    {
        alumno.seguimientos.IdAlumno = alumno.Id;

        <EditForm Model="@alumno.seguimientos">

            <div class="divEnlinea">
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 200px;">@alumno.NombreAlumno</div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 75px;">@alumno.IdCurso</div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 100px;">
                    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="alumno.seguimientos.PuntualidadEstudios">
                        <option value="">ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="SIEMPRE">SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="CASI SIEMPRE">CASI SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="A VECES">A VECES</option>
                        <option value="CASI NUNCA">CASI NUNCA</option>
                        <option value="NUNCA">NUNCA</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea" style="width: 100px;">
                    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="alumno.seguimientos.PuntualidadLevantarse">
                        <option value="">ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="SIEMPRE">SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="CASI SIEMPRE">CASI SIEMPRE</option>
                        <option value="A VECES">A VECES</option>
                        <option value="CASI NUNCA">CASI NUNCA</option>
                        <option value="NUNCA">NUNCA</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea ">
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="alumno.seguimientos.Observaciones" />
                </div>
                <div class="celdasEnLinea "><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="(()=>Guardar(alumno.seguimientos))"><span class="oi oi-reload"> Guardar</span></button></div>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    }
}
@code {
    public List<AlumnoViewModel> alumnos { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await this.CargaAlumnos();
    }

    protected async Task CargaAlumnos()
    {
        alumnos = new List<AlumnoViewModel>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            alumnos.Add(new AlumnoViewModel()
            {
                Id=i,
                NombreAlumno="Alumno " +i
            });
        }
    }
    protected void Guardar(SeguimientosInterno seguimiento)
    {
        int idalumno = seguimiento.IdAlumno;
        string p = seguimiento.PuntualidadEstudios;
    }

    public class AlumnoViewModel
    {

        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string NombreAlumno { get; set; }
        public int IdCurso { get; set; }
        public SeguimientosInterno seguimientos { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class SeguimientosInterno
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PuntualidadEstudios { get; set; }
        public string PuntualidadLevantarse { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }
        public int IdAlumno { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Realmente mas o menos las clases son así aunque el campo seguimientoInterno de AlumnosViewModel es una lista. Lo he adaptado y parece que ya va.